# GestureDetector is deprecated

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm use android stoudio 2.3.3 ,copile-v7:26.0.0-alpha1 and this method not working in this version but i tried add compile-v4:25.3.1 is my version also nothing.

```
public CandidateView(Context context) {
       ...

        mGestureDetector =  new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() { 

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1,
                                    MotionEvent e2,
                                    float distanceX,
                                    float distanceY) {
                mScrolled = true;
                int sx = getScrollX();
                sx += distanceX;
                if (sx < 0) {
                    sx = 0;
                }
                if (sx + getWidth() > mTotalWidth) {
                    sx -= distanceX;
                }
                mTargetScrollX = sx;
                scrollTo(sx, getScrollY());
                invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        });

      ...
    }
```